# How to determine a table's dependencies?

Tags: sql-server

I need to migrate some data between environments. The data structures are going to be exactly the same, however some of the data is ID dependent on existing data which will have to be adapted, or more precisely, userIds (such as ownership, last modification, etc). 
I have already established as a requirement that usernames on both environments will always refer to the same user, so what I need to do is to determine which columns reference the user table, and transform my data from one environment to the other.

I have tried checking the SQL Server Management Studio's Object dependencies on the user table, and got a detailed list of which objects are referencing the ID column. However, there is at least one table that i know that does refer the ID column that does not appear in the list.

[Constraint Options on Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAaci.png)

[Dependants on the user table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIohE.png)

Attempting to update a row from the proposal table with an unexisting id displays the expected exception:

```sql
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "OSFRK_OSUSR_tpt_PROPOSAL_OSUSR_A7L_USER_MASTER_CREATEDBY". The conflict occurred in database "databasename", table "dbo.OSUSR_A7L_USER_MASTER", column 'ID'.
```

Can there be any reason for this table to not appear as a dependent on the user's table? Is there a way to determine if there are more tables that are not being displayed?

Comment: Sounds like what you found is an implied foreign key. That is to say that the application treats the relationship like a foreign key but the database itself lacks the referential integrity to enforce it. Those kinds of things are difficult to find.

Comment: How would this be the case, since the constraints are in place and updates on the consumer table fail by virtue of the server maintaining data integrity?

Comment: Going on your comment..."However, there is at least one table that i know that does refer the ID column that does not appear in the list."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this may be it will  helpful for you.

```
EXEC sp_fkeys 'TableName'
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. It shows the table I mentioned, and taking a quick look i also noticed at least one more table that wasn't present in the original window.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following procedure, in **Object Explorer**, expand **Databases**, expand a **database**, and then expand **Tables**.

Right-click a table, and then click **View Dependencies**.

In the Object Dependencies dialog box, select either Objects that depend on , or Objects on whichdepends.

Select an object in the Dependencies grid. The type of object (such as "Trigger" or "Stored Procedure"), appears in the Type box.

Also, this link is very helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/view-the-dependencies-of-a-table?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited my question for clarity. I had provided two screenshots, but the way the text was aligned made it look like it's only one. The second screenshot shows the "Objects that depend on..." window on the users table, and the table I mentioned is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also this command:

```
USE [databasename]
GO
EXEC sp_depends @objname = 'objectname';
```

Comment: Weird, this command doesn't return anything. Or rather, it returns that "Object does not reference any object, and no objects reference it.". I supplied both the table name, and full name (with database and schema) and they both returned the same message.

Comment: Sorry, this command is for viewing the objects dependencies like tables and views. You can find more information about this command here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-depends-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017